# Is there any difference?

Tags: difference

The code of conduct would be aimed at avoiding accidents.

The code of conduct would aim to   avoid accidents.

The code of conduct would aim at avoiding accidents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as with all slight changes of wording in English, there is a difference.

"The code of conduct would be aimed at avoiding accidents."

- The use of the helping verb "would be" is passive, and fails to make a definitive statement in formal circumstances.  It's rather poorly worded.

"The code of conduct would aim to avoid accidents."

- This is slightly better (without "be"), and implies a more active function of "aiming".  It is certainly more pleasing to the ear.

"The code of conduct would aim at avoiding accidents."

- "Aim" should best be used with "to" here, because "aim[ing] at" is more like someone is using a projectile weapon and aiming it *at* something.  The phrasing still works, though.